# Android onClick slide transition to next Activity

Tags: java, android

The textview currently acts as a button to go the registration page on my app. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can apply the slide transition when the user clicks on the textview and they go to the registeractivity.

I'm not exactly experienced in using the transition library that android provides. I referred to this https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations but doesn't exactly help me with figuring out my problem.

I tried this

```
 public void onLinkClick(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    applyTransition();
}

private void applyTransition() {
    Fade fade = new Fade();
    fade.setDuration(1000);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
}
```

Applying the transition after the setcontextview but doesn't work not exactly sure how the whole "setEnterTransition" and "setExitTransition" work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While starting your activity do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, RegsiterActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_out_left);
```

Then in `res -> anim` folder:

enter_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

exit_out_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

You can modify the duration according to your needs. Here 300 means `300 milli seconds`