# Can't figure out why overridePendingTransition works in one instance but is ignored in another

Tags: android, overriding, navigation-drawer, transition

I can't figure out why when I click my "toactility" button on the following code, the `overridePendingTransition` doesn't respond at all and instead I receive a default fade in style animation. Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_navi);


    Button ToMainActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toactivity);
    ToMainActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(startIntent);

            overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.navigation_slide_left);
            finish();

        }
    });

}
```

I've tried placing `finish();` in various places, above `startActivity(startIntent);` and below it. `overridePendingTransition` is ignored.

However, on the Android hard back pressed button the `overridePendingTransition` works as expected. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.navigation_slide_left);
}
```

Can't figure out why when the `overridePendingTransition` code won't work below or above `startActivity(startIntent);`

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

From [here where I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244180/android-onclick-slide-transition-to-next-activity/47244231#47244231), use like this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_out_left);
```

Then in `res->anim` folder:

enter_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

exit_out_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

Comment: @iBEK that line should be put after startActivity() and what happens ?

Comment: It is after and I get the same kind of like a fade in animation, default animation.